# ExecuteMso during SlideShowMode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SoundRecord")
```

I run the above code during Slide Show Mode (the file is saved as .ppsm) and it shows a Debug Error. However, if I go to Slide Show Mode directly from the .pptm file, it works.

Is there any workaround for this?

My objective is for the students to record their audio in certain slides during Slide Show Mode (for a mock speaking test) and then send me the PowerPoint later.

Comment: Sorry, this is a known limitation of trying to record sound in slideshow mode with a PPSM file. It has no Ribbon, so calling a CommandBars object fails.

Comment: Is there any alternative to fulfill the objective?

Comment: Use a different format than PPSM, like PPTM.